# How to change component name dynamically in angular?

Tags: angular

The following is a custom component:

```
<app-variable-component-1></app-variable-component-1>
```

So my idea is as the user changes the input i.e clicks or select option then the current selected value will be stored in a property inside the parent component.

Like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent-component.component.less']
})
export class ParentComponentComponent implements OnInit {

currentOption = 1

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

onSelectOption(option) {
this.currentOption = option
}

}
```

using this property I want to change the component dynamically. I know I could have used `*ngIf` for each item like this:

```
<app-variable-component-1 *ngIf="currentOption === '1'"></app-variable-component-1>
<app-variable-component-2 *ngIf="currentOption === '2'"></app-variable-component-2>
<app-variable-component-3 *ngIf="currentOption === '3'"></app-variable-component-3>
```

But instead I want to shorten the code something like this:

```
<app-variable-component-{{currentOption}} ></app-variable-component-{{currentOption}}>
```

Is something similar possible in angular?

Comment: You can use ngSwitch, but what you have there is not possible

Comment: is there anything similar that I can do??

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that way is possible, but you can instance dynamic component with `ngComponentOutlet` directive. You pass the active component in directive.

***In HTML:***

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="activeComponent"></ng-container>
```

***In TS:***

```
import { Component1 } from './../component1';
import { Component2 } from './../component2';


/** ...SOME DECLARATIONS HERE.... **/

get activeComponent() {
 switch(this.currentOption) {
   case 1: return Component1;
   case 2 : return Component2;
 }
}
```

Comment: If you have a switch inside that... for what not use ngswitch or for what not use ngif in the html... 
it's the same but  with ngComponentOutlet more complicated and unnecessary

Comment: But *ngSwitch and *ngIf you have to put all components in HTML, and I think he didn't want that way.

Comment: I know...but It's not what he wants, it's what is well done

Answer (score 0):

what you have is not doable, you can use `ngSwitch` though to clean it up a bit:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="currentOption">
  <app-variable-component-1 *ngSwitchCase="'1'"></app-variable-component-1>
  <app-variable-component-2 *ngSwitchCase="'2'"></app-variable-component-2>
  <app-variable-component-3 *ngSwitchCase="'3'"></app-variable-component-3>
</div>
```

relying on selector names like that is generally not going to scale very well either way and will be difficult to maintain in a larger app.

Comment: it's not at all repetition of code. It's a switch statement.

Comment: if this is possible .. that willl be great : <app-variable-component-{{currentOption}} ></app-variable-component-{{currentOption}}>

Comment: as I said, it is not possible nor would it even be advisable. You would have a difficult to maintain and error prone application.

Comment: yeah... but this is more simpler ... right.... is there a way to create custom function or directive to achive like this <app-variable-component-{{currentOption}} ></app-variable-component-{{currentOption}}>

Comment: For the final time. NO, it is not possible.... it is less keystrokes, but it is not simpler nor is it better practice. You would have no way of checking your templates for validity as the variable could change or the selectors could change. This makes your application prone to breaks or failures. less code is not strictly better if it introduces opportunity for errors.  The only other thing you could really consider doing is abstracting this switch into a single `app-variable-switch` component of some kind that has this switch inside it and accepts input, but this adds other complexity.